# Can not open JDBC connection

Tags: java, jboss, database-connection, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

During the load test of our application, we see the exception

```
Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
```

We understand few threads blocked the connections. 
Few questions we have are
1) How many threads can share a connection?
2) how many transactions a connection can handle per second?

Our config:
maxActive db connections 10
and maxThreads in jboss 500

Comment: 1) 0 (zero) - assuming the context of a thread is also the start of a transaction and the connection has been _borrowed_; 2) not answerable - it depends on the executed queries, driver, database, network, etc.

Comment: So, thread and connection are one to one?. If Yes, when more threads are in waiting for connection and timeout happens , what's the expected error?. Can we see above exceptions in that case?

Comment: _thread and connection are one to one_ yes, assuming a thread represents the transaction boundary and the thread will at some point borrow a connection.  Yes - that timeout exception will be thrown.